# Using a json value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

So I have the following json value: `{"pages": 5}`. Pages represents the number of data I have, I want to do a loop which will create a button for the number of pages that I have (5). At the moment it's not working, I'm not too sure why.

This what I've tried:

```
$.each(pages, function () {
                $('body').append(<input type="button"/>)
                alert(pages)
                })
```

When I alert pages it gives: `{"pages": 5}` in an alert box, I'm thinking I need to do a for loop from i to 5 but I don't know how to refer to the value of pages i.e. 5.

Comment: `for (var i=0;i<pages;i++) {  $('body').append('<input type="button"/>');  }`

Comment: Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/588f2b3k/#&togetherjs=kCd283bhj7). May it help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery's `each` iterates through the values of an array or the properties of an object, it doesn't iterate a specific number of times given a number.
On top of that I think you need to turn the json into an object first since i'm pretty confident it's still considered a string at this point: `alert` doesn't show objects that way in dialogs (unlike `console.log`).
After you parse the object you can use a for loop with the `pages` property

```
var pagesObj = JSON.parse(pages);
for( var i = 0; i < pagesObj.pages; i++) {
    $('body').append('<input type="button"/>');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a *string* instead of a javascript *object*. use `JSON.parse()` to parse it as an *Object* and you should get the `key, value` in the function:

```
var newPages = JSON.parse(pages),
    btns = "";
for(var i=0; i < newPages.pages; i++){
    btns += $('<input>',{ "type"="button"});
}
$('body').append(btns);
```

Comment: The question asked for the function to output a button for each page, this will only output one.

Comment: @Joe agreed missed it completely.

Comment: @Joe just updated. This will ensure to have buttons and put them when all buttons are ready.

Comment: I like this approach, it's more optimized than adding each item to the DOM inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON value represents an object that looks like this:-

```
var json= {
    pages: 5
}
```

You can look at the pages variable like this:-

```
json.pages
```

If you want to iterate through a loop for the number of pages it would be:-

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.pages; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/ze55d2gz/)

```
var json= {
    pages: 5
};
var num= json.pages;
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    $('body').append('<input type="button"/>');
    alert("Do what ever you want");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `'`.

Use

```
$.each(pages, function () {
                $('body').append('<input type="button" value="myButton" />')
                alert(pages)
                })
```

Comment: Why did someone vote this up? `pages` is not an array or a collection. It is a number